# Sums of solutions of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

There's a question on an assignment that I'm not sure I quite understand:

Given a non-homogeneous system of equations $M$, determine for each of the following claims whether it is true or false:

1. If $\underline{c},\underline{d}$ are solutions of $M$, $(\underline{c}+\underline{d})$ is also a solution of $M$.
2. If $\underline{c},\underline{d}$ are solutions of $M$, $(3\underline{c}+2\underline{d})$ is also a solution of $M$.

Would the sum of solutions or multiples of those solutions be analogous to the sums of vectors containing the same values? I'm a little lost - some explanation would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I believe both statements are false... I've created a small, simple system to check the claims with:

$$
\begin{matrix}x+2y=1\\2x+4y=2\end{matrix}\Bigg\}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&1\\2&4&2
\end{bmatrix}\vec{R_2 \rightarrow R_2-2 \cdot R_1}\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\Rightarrow\Bigg\{\begin{matrix}x + 2y = 1\\0x+0y=0\end{matrix}\\\ \\
x+2y=1\Rightarrow x=1-2y\ ,\ y=y
$$

Conclusion: the solution set for this system is:
$$
S=\big\{(1-2y\ , \ y)\ |\ y\in R\big\}
$$

Here are two possible specific solutions to the system:

$$
(-11\ ,\ 6)\ , \ (-17\ , \ 9)\in S
$$

So if our first claim is correct that would mean:

$$
\big((-11\ ,\ 6)\ + \ (-17\ , \ 9)\big) \in S
$$

Let's check:

$$
\big((-11\ , \ 6) + (-17\ , \ 9)\big) = (-28\ , \ 15)\\\ \\
(-28\ , \ 15)\in S \Rightarrow -28=1-2(15)
$$

But since $-28\neq 1-2(15)$ the sum of the two solutions is not itself a solution of the system, so the first statement is false. Surely there are systems for which it is true, for example a system with the solution set

$$
T=\big\{(x,-x)\ |\ x\in R\big\}
$$

the first statement is actually true.

I believe that by extension of this logic the second statement is also false.

Can someone confirm or deny my claims?

Answer (score 1):

Both claim is not true in general.

say $c$ and $d$ are solutions to my non-homogeneous system of equation $Mx=y$ (so y is not a zero vector.)

so we have $Mc=y$ and $Md=y$

now $M(c+d) = 2y \neq y$ since $y$ is not a zero vector. So $(c+d)$ is not a solution.

I think you can see why $3c+2d$ is not a solution either.

Now if you are looking at a homogeneous system of equations, then statement 1 and 2 are ture.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought. Thanks!

Comment: haha. May be an upvote for me?

Comment: What about 3c-2d? Would that be a solution to my non-homogenous system?